# Cannot set up Android Management API in fully managed mode using a QR code

Tags: android, android-management-api

For work I am trying to set up multiple OEM Android tablet devices (Rockchip rk3288 / Android 8.1) as **fully managed** devices using Google's Android Management API.

Following the [quickstart steps](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) I can see that after generating an onboarding QR code I should factory reset the device and tap 6 times to scan the QR code.

Unfortunately it seems that these devices were supplied in such a way that the image does not contain the setup application - after factory reset no setup application runs and I can't find setup among the installed apps.

Does anyone know of a way that I can onbaord the devices as Fully Managed using the Android Management API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Perhaps describing what you see on the screen?

Comment: When the device is factory reset android boots right in to the home screen without running any sort of setup application, as such I cannot onboard the devices following the steps from the Android Management API guide - there's no specific error displayed as I can't even access any setup application.